# Determine if two parameters are null, then use parameters in the where clause

Tags: sql

Good day, I receive 2 nullable date parameters in my stored procedure. @StartDate and @EndDate. I need to execute my procedure as normal if these two parameters are NULL, else the @StartDate param needs to be >= my StartDateTime value AND @EndDate param needs to be <= my EndDateTime value.
Below is a snippet of what I am trying to accomplish but are not sure of the syntax.

```
    FROM DI_Intervention_Schedule S
    WHERE
        (
            @ID IS NULL
        OR  S.[ID] = @ID
        )
    AND (
            CASE @StartDate WHEN IS NOT NULL THEN
                @StartDate >= S.[StartDateTime] AND @EndDate <= S.[EndDateTime]
            END
        )
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code :

```
 FROM DI_Intervention_Schedule S
    WHERE
    (S.[ID] = @ID OR @ID IS NULL)
    AND (( S.[StartDateTime] >= @StartDate   AND S.[EndDateTime] <= @EndDate)  OR @StartDate IS NULL )
```